# On Rails, is there a shortcut to check for boolean defined variable and use its value or use a default if not defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-2

On Ruby on Rails 3, I am trying to use the value of a boolean variable, if defined, otherwise use default value true. How should I write something like this?

```
if var.defined?
  var 
else
 true
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
aVar ||= aVar.nil?
```

Which will assign the value true if the variable doesn't already have a value.

The `||=` operator assigns the right value to the left variable if the left variable doesn't have a value.  It's great for assigning default values to variables.  The `aVar.nil?` returns true if `aVar` doesn't exist or has a `nil` value.  All together it achieves what you were looking to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain how this one works? It is very strange to me that this statement does not throw "undefined local variable or method `aVar' for main:Object".

Comment: Sorry, did this late last night.  I amended the answer with an explanation.

Comment: My surprise here is that if I just type "aVar.nil?" on an irb console, it throws "NameError: undefined local variable or method ...", but if I type in the "aVar ||= aVar.nil?" it does not throw any. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: The ||= operator will always return a valid value, regardless if the variable exists, therefore it will never throw an error. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Operators

Answer (score -2):

You can try:

```
if var.present?  
 var  
else  
 true  
end
```

Comment: This does not work. Throws : "undefined local variable or method `var' for main:Object"